# how to group array value with count in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I've got a collection like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID(1),
  "fruits": [Banana, Banana, Apple]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectID(2),
  "fruits": [Apple]
}
```

I want to get the count of the array data, like 2 Banana and 1 Apple for the first object; 1 Apple for the second object.

How can i do this?

Comment: You can build an aggregation query with `$unwind` and the `$group` stages. Unwind the array field and group on the _id + fruits fields, and sum to get the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `fruits` array into multiple documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `_id` and `fruits`. Perform count.
3. `$group` - Group by `_id._id`. Push object into `fruits` array.
4. `$set` - Set `fruits` to key-value pair.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$fruits"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        fruit: "$fruits"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      fruits: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.fruit",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      fruits: {
        $arrayToObject: "$fruits"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pq5ADfbAlvI)

> Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "fruits": {
      "Apple": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "fruits": {
      "Apple": 1,
      "Banana": 2
    }
  }
]
```